# SharedPreferences Crashes on Startup on phone, but works on emulator?

Tags: java, android

I have a simple code that saves new contact info when contacts are imported, with extra properties, such as time, date, amount owed, etc that are attached. Just saving simple Strings, to retrieve in another activity and I blocked out that code just until I can figure out why it is crashing on the actual phone.

```
 @SuppressLint("Range")
    private void getContacts(View view) {
        // this method is use to read contact from users device.
        // on below line we are creating a string variables for
        // our contact id and display name.
        String contactId = "";
        String displayName = "";
        String contactEmail = "";
        String Amount = "0";
        String CurDate = "11111111";
        String DueDate = "99999999";
        String TimeCur = "0";
        String TimeDue = "0";
        // on below line we are calling our content resolver for getting contacts
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
        // on blow line we are checking the count for our cursor.
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            // if the count is greater than 0 then we are running a loop to move our cursor to next.
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                // on below line we are getting the phone number.
                int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));
                if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {
                    // we are checking if the has phone number is > 0
                    // on below line we are getting our contact id and user name for that contact
                    contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                    // on below line we are calling a content resolver and making a query
                    Cursor phoneCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                            new String[]{contactId},
                            null);
                    // on below line we are moving our cursor to next position.
                    if (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                        // on below line we are getting the phone number for our users and then adding the name along with phone number in array list.
                        String phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        contactsModalArrayList.add(new ContactsModal(displayName, phoneNumber));

                        SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(displayName, 0);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

                        String doneImport = settings.getString("DoneImport", String.valueOf(0));
                        if (!"TRUE".equals(doneImport)) {
                            editor.putString("curName", displayName);
                            editor.putString("curPhone", phoneNumber);
                            editor.putString("contactEmail", contactEmail);
                            editor.putInt("amountDue", Integer.valueOf(Amount));
                            editor.putInt("curDate", Integer.valueOf(CurDate));
                            editor.putInt("dateDue", Integer.valueOf(DueDate));
                            editor.putInt("curTime", Integer.valueOf(TimeCur));
                            editor.putInt("timeDue", Integer.valueOf(TimeDue));
                            editor.putString("DoneImport", "TRUE");
                            editor.apply();

                            //Log.i("IMPORT IS DONE", doneImport);

                        }
                    }
                    // on below line we are closing our phone cursor.
                    phoneCursor.close();
                }
            }
        }
        // on below line we are closing our cursor.
        cursor.close();
        // on below line we are hiding our progress bar and notifying our adapter class.
        loadingPB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        contactRVAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Why would this run fine on a emulator and not a android phone I have?
No crash log either when running on phone.

Crash Log

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myan, PID: 7677
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myan/com.example.myan.HomePage}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File Keaton/Matty.xml contains a path separator
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4166)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4312)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2571)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8741)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File Keaton/Matty.xml contains a path separator
    at android.app.ContextImpl.makeFilename(ContextImpl.java:3555)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.getSharedPreferencesPath(ContextImpl.java:975)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.getSharedPreferences(ContextImpl.java:573)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:226)
    at com.example.myan.HomePage.getContacts(HomePage.java:273)
    at com.example.myan.HomePage.access$100(HomePage.java:39)
    at com.example.myan.HomePage$4.onPermissionsChecked(HomePage.java:159)
    at com.karumi.dexter.DexterInstance$1.run(Unknown Source:43)
    at com.karumi.dexter.MainThread.execute(Unknown Source:6)
    at com.karumi.dexter.DexterInstance.checkMultiplePermissions(Unknown Source:71)
    at com.karumi.dexter.DexterInstance.checkPermissions(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.karumi.dexter.Dexter.check(Unknown Source:10)
    at com.example.myan.HomePage.requestPermissions(HomePage.java:187)
    at com.example.myan.HomePage.onCreate(HomePage.java:69)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8578)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8557)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1384)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4147)
```

Comment: share logs where your app is crashing

Comment: Thats the problem, when I have my phone plugged in, it reads the information part but when it crashes it leaves no error log.

Comment: did you used crashanalytics?

Comment: I did not, how do I do that? I have been using the logcat.

Comment: for crash analytics you  need to integrate Firebase or try to run on another device on which you can catch the logs on logcat

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myan/com.example.myan.HomePage}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File Keaton/Matty.xml contains a path separator

Comment: add more error log

Comment: Check Above, I added the whole log to the post.

Comment: And again this only happens when I run SharedPrefrences.

Comment: I found the problem, there is a contact in the phone that is named Keaton/Matty and that slash is causing the crash. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, there is a contact in the phone that is named Keaton/Matty and that slash is causing the crash I Just Renamed it and now it works perfect.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).